# how to hide native loading gauge in iPad and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad

I am developing app that supports iPad and iPhone. I am using custom html loading image for my app. but while loading some pages or images two loading gauges get displayed(iOs loading gauge and custom loading gauge). How to hide this native loading gauge in my app? I want to show only custom loading gauge.

Comment: would you show me your code.I can't guess what you are doing.